# After opting out from the long-term care payroll tax in Washington by purchasing a qualifying long-term-care insurance, can one drop the insurance?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, payroll-taxes, washington, termination

After opting out from the newly established long-term care payroll tax in Washington state by purchasing a qualifying long-term-care insurance, can one terminate the contract with the insurance? Or does one have to keep paying for the insurance every year?

Comment: It certainly should be designed that you have to keep it, but whether they actually check I don't know.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Thanks. In Should land, that tax would have never existed.

Comment: The state is tired of paying for Medicaid for freeloaders who don't get insurance.

Comment: @LorenPechtel true but with the opt-out close, only freeloaders and low income earners will not opt out. That's why LTC insurances have been inundated with applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, according to 3 insurance brokers I talked to. They told me that if an audit from the WA tax services sees that one has terminated the insurance, one would get some penalties (likely paying the 0.58% on the W2 income of the years without the long-term care insurance + some penalties). Obviously one can claim that the insurance brokers are biased, so if someone else can confirm and deny, preferably via a legal text, that'd be great.